# private fields in android studio

Tags: java, android, field, private

when I use private in my code it then gives me an error saying the field is never assigned and then the emulator crashes.

I saw other information from stackoverflow and someone who had the same question but they had not actually used their fields which is why they had the error so I am posting from a different point of view.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

            Button falseButton; //this works
    private Button trueButton; //when i add private it then says true button field is not being used
    private TextView questionTextView; //this also gets an error when i use private

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        falseButton.findViewById(R.id.buttonFalse);
        trueButton.findViewById(R.id.buttonTrue);
        questionTextView.findViewById(R.id.textView);

        falseButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()){
            case R.id.buttonFalse:
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "False", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case R.id.buttonTrue:
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "True", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

I then should be able to open the emulator press the button and get a toast pop up but the app fails.

Comment: Your buttons and the textview are used in `onCreate`. This should still work even if the fields are made private. Is there anything else in your code that you didn't include in your question?

Comment: I have no other code except the layout XML which is an image view, textview and 2 buttons. And the question is why does it error when I make the field private? And also Is my way of making an on click listener valid?

Comment: Please follow some good android tutorials. You are using null objects, they are initialize using  this.findViewById(R.id.buttonFalse); 
 R.id.buttonFals this is Id which you define in your activity_main.xml file.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your statement @manmohan I am doing a Udemy course and with the exception of my layout being a constraint layout and his a linear layout the code is otherwise the same. his has worked fine but mine is throwing up errors

Comment: Use you code portion with this: 
        `falseButton = findViewById(R.id.buttonFalse);
           trueButton = findViewById(R.id.buttonTrue);
           questionTextView = findViewById(R.id.textView);`  Hope it will work

Comment: @Saadat thank you. I did not notice that. that's fixed the issue. which i guess is what manmohan was trying to say. the app works now... simple typo took me half a day... each mistake is a learning opportunity :D

Comment: @Mr J, you are welcome. :)

Comment: @Mr J let replace  .  operator and use =

Comment: e.g falseButton = findViewById(R.id.buttonFalse);
        trueButton = findViewById(R.id.buttonTrue);
        questionTextView = findViewById(R.id.textView);

Answer (score 0):

@Saadat solved it. it was my fault, a simple typo:

I had

```
falseButton.findViewById(R.id.buttonFalse);
trueButton.findViewById(R.id.buttonTrue);
questionTextView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
```

But i should have had = instead of a .

```
falseButton = findViewById(R.id.buttonFalse); 
trueButton = findViewById(R.id.buttonTrue); 
questionTextView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
```